# Implementation PubNub for VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, webrtc, pubnub

On official site i didn't find any example of using **`PubNub`** with **VB.Net**.

Does it implemented for **VB.Net** and if yes, give some tutorials for it?

Comment: there is a NET SDK, so why wouldn't it work with VB?

Comment: @Plutonix, it use c# as base language

Comment: So convert the code to VB.NET ... It is not that difficult (just study a little bit of syntax or else use a code converter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## PubNub VB.Net Quick Start

You might consider using PubNub Simple HTTP REST API and here are a few links for using Visual Basic .NET with PubNub.  Since we don't have an official VB.NET API you can find really easy to use options.

- [HTTP Streaming over TCP with Telnet Example](http://www.pubnub.com/community/discussion/14/http-streaming-over-tcp-with-telnet-example)
- [PubNub HTTP REST API](http://www.pubnub.com/http-rest-push-api/)

[image: Publishing via HTTP Example]